# Speed optimization: Optimize render blocking scripts with async

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, pagespeed, render-blocking

On https://bm-translations.de (fully self coded, no cms etc.) I am trying to eliminate render blocking of `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Defer isnt working as I have another script at the end of the page `<script src="globaljs.js"></script>` that contains Bootstrap and jquery lazyloading etc as well as inline Javascript after it. I thought I could give `async` to all of them. At first I thought its working but from time to time (like random) its showing this:

[image]

I wondered if there is any other option or a way to ensure the render blocking jquery is loaded before the scripts at the bottom of the page but without render blocking?

Comment: Scripts that are downloaded via `script` tag with `async` attribute are not guarantee to load in exact order, as far as I know. The order is important in your case, so either it should happen synchronously (i.e., no `async` attribute given to the respective `script` tag), or some programming is required (for example, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24268791/1287643). But then, typically to eliminate render blocking, placing all `script` tags as the very last children of `document.body` should help.

Comment: You'd need to give both of them the `defer` attribute. Or you just move jQuery down to the end of the body as well?

Comment: placing it below the fold but above the lazyload script was the solution. All other things resulted in layout-problems. Thanks for your hints! :-)
Any other performance hints are very welcome and I will give the bounty to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below approach to load the script sequentially with promises.

On DOMContentLoaded`` load the script sequentials and to load the scripts async you could use the ES6 promises.

**Sample code:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function(event) {
    await loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js");
    await loadScript("globaljs.js");
});

function loadScript(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let file = document.createElement('script');
        file.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(file);
        file.onload = file.onreadystatechange = function() {
            resolve(true);
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`bm-translations.de` doesn't need optimization of jquery loading, personal opinion. jQuery script doesn't block rendering, it is already placed at bottom

As far as I understood at the bottom of page there are 2 scripts. First is jquery, and second is dynamic, generated by server side for each page separately, which connects dynamic behavior to the HTML

BTW - Possible alternatives to placing JS before `</body>` end tag:

- Build your scripts

  - just concatenate your scripts via script (for old projects this could work well)
  - use `browserify`, `webpack`, etc.
- use `RequireJS` which could handle async scripts loading and loads dependencies
- write custom JS which guarantees load order

But all these approaches seems to be not applicable to `bm-translations.de`