# Load dynamic js files in order with async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Sometime i have no order because async nature.
When my dynamic script loads in no order than errors happen.

Starts on node.js app [also async]:

```js
function GET_FILES_NAME(path, name_of_go, main_length) {
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    for(var i = 0;i < items.length;i++) {
      console.log("VISUAL SCRIPT FOR POST LOAD ::::::::::", items[i]);
      io.sockets.emit(
        "RETURN",
        "LOAD_SCRIPT",
        "cache/" + name_of_go + "/" + items[i]
      );
    }
  });
}
```

```js
    LOCAL_COMMUNICATOR.on("RETURN", function(action, data) {
      if (action == "LOAD_SCRIPT") {
        console.log("LOAD_SCRIPT: " + data);
        SYS.SCRIPT.LOAD(data);
      } 
   })
```

```js
export var SCRIPT = {
  SCRIPT_ID: 0,
  LOAD: async function addScript(src, isAsync) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      if (typeof isAsync !== 'undefined') s.type = "module";
      s.onload = function () {
        SCRIPT.SCRIPT_ID++;
        console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m',
          "Script id loaded [" +
            SCRIPT.SCRIPT_ID +
            "] : " +
            this.src
        );
        var filename = this.src.substring(
          this.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
          this.src.lastIndexOf(".")
        );
        filename = filename.replace(".", "_");
        resolve('Async js code block loaded and executed.');
        console.log('LOaded -> ' + filename)
      };
      s.setAttribute("src", src);
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    })
  }
};
```

lets say i have `a2.js`, `a3.js`

Sometimes browser load `a3.js` then `a2.js` (bad situation).

I found this QA [async loading js scripts - guarantee they load in right order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268791/async-loading-js-scripts-guarantee-they-load-in-right-order) but in mine case i don't have simple array also i dont wanna buffer that data.

Any suggest how to make it in order.

Comment: Where are you calling `SCRIPT.LOAD(data)` multiple times with scripts that depend on each other?

Comment: "*Sometimes browser load `a3.js` then `a2.js`*" - no, surely they are loaded at the same time. What happens is that `a3.js` may load **faster**, and then be executed before another script that started to load earlier.

Comment: "*i don't have simple array also i dont wanna buffer that data*" - then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Maybe you are right , i will post feedback if i find someway ...

Comment: You'll need to have either a list with the order set, or a way to define the dependencies of each script... Only then will you be able to handle the order correctly.

Comment: "*bad situation*" - no, this is a solved problem: use [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api)

Comment: I will send from node.js part length [sum of files] and that on client part i will push and then on last i will get it ordered async! it is not the best but it is solution for now.